# How to load dynamically generated html?

Tags: html, menu, cascadingdropdown

I develop a primefaces project. Since primefaces's dynamically generated menus are not capable of showing tooltips(or it was my fault), I tried to generate a html menu with almost 10K nodes as string and load it. However, the page was opened in almost 10 seconds.This decreased the performance too much. I basically need to have server side generated menu data, tooltips on menuitems. Is there any way to achieve this?

```
 @ApplicationScoped
 @ManagedBean
 public Class MenuManagedBean{

 private String htmlCode;

 public void menuHtml(){
 //here I generate all <li>'s and data inside it.
 }

  public void setHtmlCode(String htmlCode) {
   this.htmlCode= htmlCode
}

public String gethtmlCode() {
   return htmlCode;
}
 }
```

In xhtml page:

```
  <h:form> <p:outputLabel value=#{menuManagedBean.htmlCode} escape="false" </form>
```

Comment: Why is that a JSF problem? Looks like a plain HTML problem. JSF can't do much if the webbrowser is having trouble digesting 10K HTML nodes.

Comment: Yes, you are right. My problem with Primefaces is showing dynamic tooltips in dynamic tiered menu. Since it did not work, I tried html. I also removed the JSF tag, thanks BalusC.

Comment: But html people cannot help with this. They do not see what you generate...